# How can I manipulate 2D arrays in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I've been studying for my upcoming Java exam, and i'm having a hard time wrapping my head around 2D arrays. I have the basics down, such as creating and initializing a 2D array, but when it comes to inserting, deleting, or even sorting through one, I get pretty confused. My professor spent all of 10 minutes going over the basics but on our exam, we are expected to know how to create a 2D array of objects and manipulate the data by inserting, deleting, and sorting the objects in the array. He makes us hand-write all of our code on our exams, so no computers are allowed to assist in the process. I've spent hours pouring over examples both here and on other sites, but I still don't feel like I understand the material well enough to hand write all my code and get it right.

My confusion mostly stems from the nested `for` loops usually used to move thru a 2D array. I can see how other people do it and copy that, but I still don't understand *why* the loops work as they do. I'm sure i'm in the minority here, but for whatever reason the logic behind it has me completely lost.

Take this(albeit poor) example i've been working on to help myself understand 2D arrays(as well as the rest of the exam material). Say you run a car dealership and you want to order cars to fill your stock. The program starts with a top `abstract` class that describes the cars you are selling in general(in my case Audi). The dealership offers 4 models of Audi's, an `A4`, `A6`, `A8`, and `R8`. All these cars(classes) inherit methods from the `super`, named `Audi`. I then want to create a 2D array to store the cars in stock. This will be used in another class defined by me, including methods to `search()`, `delete()`, and `sort()`. Let's call it `AudiDealership`. The dealer can only hold 3 of each model, so the array would be something like `Audi[4][3]`. The A4's would fill the first row, `subscript 0`, A6 fills `subscript 1`, ect. How would I set up the `for` loops to insert/delete from the proper row? I obviously don't want an A4 inserted into a row that should hold an A6, and so on.

Again, I can stare at code all day and copy it, but I want to **understand** *why*/*how* the loops work as they do. I apologize if this topic seems trivial or has been beaten to death, but all the reading i've done before posting this has left me just as confused as before. Many of you on this site are fantastic teachers in your own right, so I thought someone may be able to explain this in a way that I can understand. My professor hasn't been any help in this regard, so i'm using external means to try and figure things out. I greatly appreciate any advice or explanation in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you read this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html It's a great resource for understanding how to deal with arrays. If you understand how to work with a single array, a 2D array is simply an array of arrays, so once you grap the concept that would be more easy to understand it.

Comment: [Concise Explanation of Two-dimensional arrays](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think of 2D arrays as arrays that hold other arrays. Such as `Cars[0][5]` is accessing a car array at 0 and the actual car is found in position 5 of that array. `Cars[1][5]` would access the second car array at position 1 and the car is found at 5 of the array that's in position 1. This code might help you understand it a bit more:

```
public class TwoDArray {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {      
    Cars[][] cars; // declaring my 2D array.

    cars = new Cars[4][]; // making the x axis 4 cars wide.

    // now we will step along the x axis and create a Cars array in each slot.
    for ( int a = 0; a < cars.length; a++) // cars.length = how wide.
    { 
        cars[a] = new Cars[3]; // creating a new Cars[] in each slot of our 2D Car array @ position a.
                               //cars[a] = new 1D Cars array in slot a, length of 3.
    }

    // Note that we could have also created our array like this.
    // Cars[][] cars = new Cars[4][3];


    for ( int x = 0; x < cars.length; x++) //stepping along the x axis. cars.length = how wide.
    {   //every time we step thru x we will execute this next loop.
        for ( int y = 0; y < cars[x].length; y++) // stepping along the y axis. cars[x].length = how long.
        { // this loop will cycle through the y axis each time we increment x
            cars[x][y] = new Cars( 2014, "someAudi", x + " " + y ); // creating a new car(s) @ x,y position.
        }
    }

    // now to just print them.

    for ( int x = 0; x < cars.length; x++) //stepping along the x axis again.
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < cars[x].length; y++) // stepping along the y axis.
        {
            System.out.println(cars[x][y].getYear() + 
                    " " + cars[x][y].getModel() +
                    " " + cars[x][y].getName() +
                    " " + cars[x][y].getManufacturer()); // the super method.
        }
    }

    //INSERTION. 

    // To insert into your array, you simply need to provide the coordinates to insert the new Car(s) object.
    // This next line will insert a new Car into the array at position 1 and the number 2 element of that array.
    cars[1][2] = new Cars( 2014, "someAudi", "My Favorite Car!");

    System.out.println(); // Just adding a space between outputs.

    for ( Cars[] c: cars) //extracting each Cars array and name it c from the 2D Cars array named cars.
    {                     //basically stepping along the x axis and getting each array stored in x.

        for ( Cars car: c) // Now we are stepping along the y axis.
        {                  // We are getting each individual Cars object and naming it car
                           // from each Cars[] named c from our first loop.

            System.out.println(car.getYear() + 
                    " " + car.getModel() +
                    " " + car.getName() +
                    " " + car.getManufacturer()); // the super method.
        }
    }

    // NOTE* if you wish to insert a new element and do not have extra capacity then you will need to
    // create a larger array @ cars[x]. cars[x] = new Cars[newSize];. 

    // DELETION.

    // To delete an element you can just simply overwrite it. 
    // such as:        
    cars[1][1] = new Cars( 2014, "someAudi", "new Audi"); // Essentially we deleted and inserted a new object
                                                          // at position [1][1]. 

    // If you just want to completely remove the element then you will need to update the size of the array.

    // You can define a new array to hold the values of the old array minus the element that should be deleted.
    Cars[] newArray = new Cars[cars[2].length - 1]; // We will use the array stored in cars[2] for this example.
                                                    // we set the length to one less to completely get rid of the
                                                    // old element.    

    int deleteThisPosition = 1; // We will use this variable to store the position that will be deleted from
                                // the array stored in cars[2].

    int newArrayPosition = 0; // We will use this to increment our position in the new array along with `a`
                              // in the next for loop.

    for ( int a = 0; a < cars[2].length; a++)
    {
        if ( a == deleteThisPosition) // if it reaches this position we will advance `a` and exclude it from
             a++;                     // our new array.

        newArray[newArrayPosition] = cars[2][a]; // we will store the value @ position `a` from the array in cars[2]
                                                 // into our newArray @ position `newArrayPosition`.                                     

        newArrayPosition++; // incrementing our variable to stay parallel with the array in cars[2]. 
    }

    //Now we can just assign the newArray to cars[2]. You will notice that Car `2 1` is no longer present.
    cars[2] = newArray;

    System.out.println(); // Just adding a space between outputs.

    for ( Cars[] c: cars) 
    {                                 
        for ( Cars car: c) 
        {                                 
            System.out.println(car.getYear() + 
                    " " + car.getModel() +
                    " " + car.getName() +
                    " " + car.getManufacturer()); // the super method.
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Here are the other classes from your example.

Audi class:

```
public abstract class Audi { 

  public String getManufacturer() { return "Audi"; } // method from this super class.

}
```

Cars class:

```
public class Cars extends Audi{ //extending Audi.

  private String model;
  private String name;
  private int year;

  Cars(int year, String model, String name)
  {
    this.year = year;
    this.model = model;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }    

  public String getModel() { return model; }

  public int getYear() { return year; }

}
```

If you run the code you will notice the pattern in the names of the cars.

Output:

[image]

Notice the pattern in each car's name, the unique column. It corresponds to how we stepped through our loops. We started with x and for each x we looped through y. `x + " " + y` was how we named each car in the code above.

Comment: Amazing example! This helps me understand how the loops actually move thru the array. Your comments made the code easily readable, and I know how it's functioning during each iteration. Thanks a ton :) Why my prof couldn't construct something like that is beyond me.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help.

Comment: I updated my answer to include insertion and deletion, just incase you still needed some help with those as well. Also added enhanced for loops incase you would like to understand those as well. You can ignore the enhanced loops if you like as I only use them to print out the arrays.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've been playing around with some code since you posted this(before the insertion and deletion) and I think i'm starting to get the hang of it! With the rest you added, i'll feel a lot more comfortable come test time on monday. I really appreciate your helpful input. People like you are what make the programming community so awesome sometimes :)

Comment: As far as the enhanced for loops, i've used em a few times w regular arrays and my prof briefly went over them in class last week, but I never really got the gist of it, so thanks for adding that. I'm always down to learn something new, so the convenience of less code when referring to enhanced loops is something I should probably get more familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            output.append(table[i][j]);
        }
        output.append("\n");
    }
```

This would be the code to loop through a 2 dimensional array.

[image: array image]

The code goes directly into the first row. This is the i-value.
As you want to loop through every column of the row, 
you need to know the length of the row to loop through it.

So you start in the first row, and go right to the end which is table[i].length.
In the first row the first length would be table[0].length.
And this length is 3 as you have 3 columns in each row.

[image: entry point]

As we're now done with looping through the first row, we get to second row.
By going into the second row i increases by one.
So our pointer shows now in row 2 (The **i**  in table[i].length is now 1 because it always starts at 0) and so on.

Our pointer goes through every row and thats just how it works.
with every new row the pointer of **i** increases by 1 (that's the **i++** in the for loop).

[image]

With every new column in one row the **j** increases and the **i** stays the same.
The **i** only changes when you're entering a new row. 
And the **j** changes by entering a new column.

Hope this helps ;)

EDIT.:

Another example :

if you would like to get the value of the 3rd column in the 4th row:
[image]

The value you want is inside here: `table[3][2];`
Remember arrays always start counting at 0. :)

Comment: Wow, the visual helped a ton! For whatever reason that was the hardest part for me, the visualization. Along with your explanation of each section, I feel like I understand it much better than before. I'm still not 100% but I can play with some code and hopefully figure it out. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: no problem :), I had the same problems when starting. Feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Audi[4][3] cars = ... // your 2D array of all cars
```

As you correctly specified,

> The A4's would fill the first row, subscript 0, A6 fills subscript 1, ect.

which translates to `cars[0]` holds `Audi[] with A4 instances`, `cars[1]` holds `Audi[] with A6 instances` etc.

OK, so

```
 Audi[] A4s = cars[0];
 Audi[] A6s = cars[1];
 ...
```

Then you could say that

```
 Audi A4_1 = A4s[0];
 Audi A4_2 = A4s[1];
 Audi A4_3 = A4s[2];
 ...
```

And repeat it for each car you have. But this is a wrong approach. First we generalize access to each car.

If you want to traverse specific cars in each model array, you need to have a for-loop with index called, say, `specificCarIndex`. Loop to traverse an array of `A4s` will be simple:

```
 for (int specificCarIndex = 0; specificCarIndex < 3; specificCarIndex++) {
      // Here A4s[specificCarIndex] contains an object of concrete Audi car of model A4
  }
```

To traverse array of another model (like A6) you do the same, replacing `A4s` with `A6s` and so on.

Now we need to generalize everything.

```
  for (int carModelIndex = 0; carModelIndex < 4; carModelIndex++) {
      // Here cars[carModelIndex] holds an array of specific Audi model as you mentioned before
  }
```

`cars[carModelIndex]` essentially is `Audi[] A4s` if `carModelIndex == 0`, then `Audi[] A6s` if `carModelIndex == 1` and so on.

Now that we know how to access array of each Audi model, and we know how to access individual cars in each model array, we combine the two:

```
 for (int carModelIndex = 0; carModelIndex < 4; carModelIndex++) {
     for (int specificCarIndex = 0; specificCarIndex < 3; specificCarIndex++) {
         // Here cars[carModelIndex][specificCarIndex] holds an object of type Audi which refers to a specific car
         // If double index seems difficult, consider this:
         // Audi[] audis = cars[carModelIndex] (array like A4s, A6s...)
         // Audi audi = audis[specificCarIndex] (specific car)
         // Just as in the examples before for-loops.
     }    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for relating to one of my specific questions, which was how to search for a specific car in the array itself. Also, your variable names helped me understand what each block of the loop is doing in relation to my example. It will be hard to choose an answer as you all have brought something helpful to the table :)